# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type List

Tags: flutter, datatable, flutter-futurebuilder

I have been trying to convert my app to new flutter new version but I got this error The argument type `Object?` can't be assigned to the parameter type `List` that can't be fix.... can somebody help me fix this problem

```
list() {
    return Expanded(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: employees,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return dataTable(List<Url>.from(snapshot.data));
          }

          if (null == snapshot.data || snapshot.data == 0) {
            return Text("Tiada Data");
          }

          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you need to cast the type of your `FutureBuilder`. Based on your code I deduce that `employees` is of type `Future<List>` or at least `Future<Iterable>` then you should define the type of your builder like this:

```dart
FutureBuilder<Iterable>(
  future: employees,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return dataTable(List<Url>.from(snapshot.data!));
    }

    // ...
  },
),
```

Comment: The argument type 'List<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<dynamic>' i got this error

Comment: What is the type of your variable employees ?

Comment: You might simply need to force cast as non nullable your `snapshot.data` like this: `List<Url>.from(snapshot.data!)`

Comment: late Future<List<Url>> employees;